# Java 8 distinct elements in a stream

Tags: java, java-8

I want to have latest and distinct events. So if event occured for product "ball" 10 times in a day and it was event of type "kick" than I just need the latest event when somebody kicked the ball.

```
public class Event {
    private Date eventDate;
    private EventType eventType;
    private Long productId;

    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        Event that = (Event) o;

        if (eventDate != null ? !eventDate.equals(that.eventDate) : that.eventDate != null)
            return false;
        if (eventType != that.eventType)
            return false;
        return productId != null ? productId.equals(that.productId) : that.productId == null;
    }

    @Override 
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = eventDate != null ? eventDate.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (eventType != null ? eventType.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (productId != null ? productId.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}

List<Event> events = 
    actions.getEvent(requestedEvents)
           .stream()
           .map(event -> new Event(event))
           .distinct()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Event::getEventDate))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This doesn't work :( It gets distinct events but it still returns more than one kind of event (eventType + productId) and I want to have only the latest one per pair eventType and productId.

I would like to do it without overriding equals and hashcode, but it would be even harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure it’s worth using Streams and lambdas for this, but here you go:

```
Collection<Event> events = allEvents.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(e -> Arrays.asList(e.getType(), e.getProductId()),
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Event::getEventDate)),
            Optional::get))).values();
```

Breaking this down:

- The resulting collection needs to have a single Event for each combination of product and event type, so Collectors.groupingBy creates a Map whose keys are based on Arrays.asList(e.getType(), e.getProductId()).
- Each corresponding value in the Map would normally be a `List<Event>`, if the single-argument Collectors.groupingBy method were used; so instead of that, we use the two-argument form, which accepts an additional Collector that is applied to that `List<Event>`.
- Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Event::getEventDate)) replaces the `List<Event>` with the latest Event in that List.  However, since maxBy has no guarantee that the List will be non-empty, it returns an `Optional<Event>` rather than an Event instance.
- But we know for sure that every List will have at least one element (or it wouldn’t have been placed in the Map by groupingBy in the first place), so we can safely map every Optional to the value wrapped by the Optional.  To do that, we wrap Collectors.maxBy in Collectors.collectingAndThen, which passes the result of maxBy to Optional::get.
- The Map generated by this big Collectors.groupingBy call is a `Map<List<Object>, Event>`.  At this point, we can ignore the map’s keys, and just return its values.

For what it’s worth, you can use the java.util.Objects class to make your `equals` and `hashCode` methods shorter:

```
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Event) {
        Event that = (Event) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.eventDate, that.eventDate) &&
               this.eventType == that.eventType &&
               Objects.equals(this.productId, that.productId);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override 
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(eventDate, eventType, productId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `distinct()` on a stream of `SynchronizationEvent` instances :

```
stream().map(event -> new SynchronizationEvent(event)).distinct()
```

But the `equals()` method is defined for the `Event` class.
Besides, it is not specificed but even if `SynchronizationEvent` is a subclass of `Event`, it will not work either as your equals() implementation doesn't allow to compare subclasses of `Event`s :

```
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
   ...
}
```

If `SynchronizationEvent` is a subclass, you should rather use the `instanceof` operator to check if the current object is a `Event` object or an object of any subclass of it :

```
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Event)
          return false;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, there is no SynchronizationEvent,  just Event, I corrected the question. I just dont now how to return only the latest event of each type. Dates can be null, then only one event with null date per eventType. Everything in simple list as result.

Comment: With your modifications, this is still not clear as  the Event constructor takes an event as parameter. This constructor is not shown in the code. And whatever, which is the logic behind ? It is hard to provide a solution that suits to your needs, if they are not explicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Collection<Event> col = 
    actions.getEvent(requestedEvents)
               .stream()
               .map(event -> new Event(event))
               .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                e -> e.eventType + "-" + e.productId, v -> v,
        (k1, k2) -> Long.compare(k1.eventDate.getTime(),k2.eventDate.getTime()) > 0 ? k1 : k2))
.values();
```

Since you don't want to override equals and hashCode, you can use the eventType+productId as key in map and merge the values for the same keys on the eventDate ordering. Finally you can pull all the values from the map.